# (false - NOT (0)) is equal to 1?

Tags: c++

A test question: What is the result of `(false - ~0)`

Why `(false - ~0)` is `1`? On 32 bit machine `~0` is `11....11` where there are 32 `1` bits right? Then false to int conversion is `00....00` also 32 times, right? So we subtract from 32 `0` 32 `1`? Does it underflow and we get 1?

Comment: std::map<std::string, std::vector<unsigned long long>>

Comment: re @thomasMacleod: your question is wrong - you subtract from 32 `0` 32 `-1`.

Comment: 32 `-1`is more genius then `what is the type of '-' in this instance?` :D

Comment: @AlexBrown, I'm not following you.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod - you are correct.  I was pointing out that in the light of your (excellent) answer, the original question is wrong: "So we subtract from 32 0 32 1?" isn't what happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`0` is `int` → `~0` is `int` and equal `-1` → `false` gets promoted to `int`, which results in zero → your expression is calculated as `(0 - (-1))` which equals `1`.

Answer (score 9):

`~0` evaluates to -1 in 2s-complement representation. So 0 - -1 does equal 1.

**Edit:**
To be slightly more precise. The unary `~` operator applied to the literal `0`, which is an `int`, is a bit-wise one's complement operator. The memory representation of `0` then becomes `0xffffffff` in 32-bit architectures. However, the result is still type `int`. Since all popular compilers interpret memory representation of `int` in two's complement, `~0` evaluates to `-1`.

Comment: Holds true as long as we consider it signed. But if we define ~0 as `unsigned int` still it gives 1

Comment: @Atul, in C++, the literal `0` is a signed int. See 2.14.2.2 of the ISO C++ standard.

Comment: Well even if we do like this: `unsigned int zeros = 0; unsigned int ones = 0xFFFFFFFF; unsigned int answer = zeros - ones;` still `answer` hold value 1

Comment: @Atul, the operation in your second comment would cause an `unsigned int` overflow except that the standard says that "Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer." see section 3.9.1.4 So `-0xffffffff` mod 2^32 does equal 1. But this is not the same expression as the question. There both operands of the subtraction were after promotions just `int`.

Comment: I suspect you meant *'The unary `~` operator'* not *'The unitary...'*